# Must a Personal Profile be Used to Access the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to access Facebook data using the Graph API from an external commercial application. I've created a login for my company and gather that I need to register a Facebook App in order to use the Graph API.

However, I am confused about the Facebook requirement to associate a Personal Profile (a real person) with the Facebook App. Why must a person become connected to my organization's application?

What if I leave the organization? Will the company I worked for need to pick another employee in order to access the Graph API?

Surely I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Your question here seems to be about the Facebook API in general and registering an app for it, rather than the Graph API per se.  The answer to the general question is that, as with the Twitter API and certain Google APIs, the personal account is used as part of the process of validating that the app is tied to a real person.  Luckily, there's a good solution in place for handling when app developers no longer work for a company: another app developer can remove them from the app.  You can list someone else on your team as a developer of the app and they will have the same rights to edit it as you do.